# How to import/add all packages in a julia project?

Tags: julia

When I download a Julia library and try to execute the tests it gives the following message:

> Got exception outside of a @test
> LoadError: ArgumentError: Package OrdinaryDiffEq not found in current path:

> - Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("OrdinaryDiffEq")` to install the OrdinaryDiffEq package.

After that I run the required commands and the dependency gets installed. Now when I run the tests again it will show the same message just with another dependency.
Is there a way to add all of the Packages at once?

Comment: What was the library? What was the next dependency?

Comment: >After that I run the required commands and the dependency gets installed

what exactly did you run

Answer (score 1):

You can activate the test folder of that package (`using Pkg; Pkg.activate("/that/path`) and then run `Pkg.instantiate()`.

This will download and build the pkg that you may missing and make you in the conditions to run the test.

Note: this should work for newer pkgs that use a separate Project.toml file for testing, not sure for old packages that still specify the dependencies used for test as a subsection of the main pkg Project.toml file.

Comment: Don't you need also to `]add OrdinaryDiffEq` after `] activate`?

Comment: This may contain the answer but what is a "test folder" and what is "\that\path"?